# Remove old Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I am using Cordova to build a mobile app. I was trying to find some gesture detection plugins to add some swiping features to the app. I installed a plugin "com.rossgerbasi.cordova.plugins.glass.Glass" but no longer need it. I had issues trying to uninstall it. I have ran **cordova remove plugin com.rossgerbasi.cordova.plugins.glass.Glass** with some errors. I was able to successfully remove it after some googling and when I run **cordova plugin list** it is no longer there.

So I removed and readded the ios and android platforms. However now when I run **cordova run android** the app builds and is installed on my device but immediately crashes with a **ClassNotFoundException: com.rossgerbasi.cordova.plugins.glass.Glass**.

I did a search in the C drive for rossgerbasi and it found a few results including references to it in *platform\android*. I deleted them all and deleted the entry for it in the android config.xml but that file is automagically generated so after I run the app that entry returns. There is still something somewhere still holding onto this plugin and adding it to my app. What do I need to do to remove this plugin from my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up fixing the problem. I did another search inside files for the text **rossgerbasi** inside my project directory. I found a reference to it inside a handful of files. I deleted the references to this plugin in those files and now the app runs again. There was a reference to it still in *cordova_plugins.js* and I am guessing that is the one causing the issues. My guess is it tells Cordova which plugins to use. For some reason after I ran *cordova remove* to remove that plugin it was not removed from this file like it should have been. If someone can tell me if I am correct that would be great.

Comment: All required plugin info will be stored in fetch.json file inside plugins folder. To remove the dependency of plugin after deleting the plugin folder manually, its better remove respective platforms once and re-add it. Most importantly the reference from fetch.json file also needs to be removed. cordova_plugin.js references will go off automatically once you remove platform, remove reference ion fetch.json and re-add plaform. Hope it helps. Keep me posted

Comment: Thanks I looked and it was also still in fetch.json so I removed it from there as well.

Comment: Removing it from fetch.json was all that is required

Comment: I will keep that in mind if this ever happens again.

Answer (score 1):

If running `cordova plugin rm <plugin_id>` doesn't do the trick, then what I've done in the past is just remove the plugin manually. I remove the plugin folder under `<cordova_project>/plugins/<plugin>`. I also remove the plugin entry in `<cordova_project>/plugins/<platform.json>` & `<cordova_project>/plugins/fetch.json`

Answer (score 1):

If you remove plugin from plugin folder manually (which is generally not advisable), to remove the plugin dependency do the following:

1. Remove existing platforms
2. Remove required plugin reference from `fetch.json` file available under `plugins` folder
3. Re-add required platform and rebuild it